# Core dump when the code is called through a web interface

Tags: php, apache

Here's the hard-core problem.

I have a piece of code written in C++. The code is part of a website, run on Apache and built using PHP. Every time a user submits some data, the code will process those data. However, the code always throws coredump error (signal 11) when called through the web interface. It runs no problem at all in the shell under my own username. I also tried to run it as user www-data and it works well.

So my question is really down to Why it doesn't run when called through the web interface and how to fix it?

The OS is Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64.

Many many thanks.

Comment: If you are sure it is not a permissions error than it sounds like the input you are giving this program via the web interface is different than when you run it personally on your server. No one can tell you more than that.

Comment: Well, I copied whole input directory structure to a local location and re-ran the code. Annoyingly, it worked fine. So, I really don't know the cause. Thanks for the answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of help from valgrind, I finally solved the mystery. The problem lies with a line of a header file, which tries to read "$USER", using getenv("USER"). While the env parameter is set in my local shell, it's unset when the code is called through the web interface. Not sure why it's unset though. After exporting the env parameter, everything is fine now.

Hope this may help someone one day.